# Forcing a generic parameter to be either serializable or primitive value ( int for examplt) C#

Tags: c#, serialization, b-tree

These are classes I've created. The Tree uses the node.

```
public class BMinTreeNode<T> : Serialization.ISerializable where T:   IComparable, Serialization.ISerializable
```

```
public class BMinTree<T> where T:   IComparable, Serialization.ISerializable
```

This is an instantiation of the class.

```
BMinTree<int> costIndexTree = new BMinTree<int>();
```

I want the class to work with either string or int.
I'm using serialization for the node.

I get an error message from the compiler that type int isn't ISerializable.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Type constraints aren't OR, they're AND.

Comment: Well, `System.Int32` doesn't implement `ISerializable` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32).  You'll need to relax (i.e., remove) that constraint if you want `T` to include `int`.  Your code can include different paths depending on whether `T` implements `ISerializable` or not.  Otherwise, you are mostly stuck